# Alwayson AG lease timeout and healthcheck timeout

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, clustering, database-internals

We have a physical SQL Server 2016 Enterprise SP2 with two instances and each instance contains one AG.
Sometimes it happens that one AG goes to resolving (without failover), the cluster resource is automatically restarted after 500ms and then everything is back online.
But I've not yet been able to find a cause.

When I'm checking the Errorlog, I see following entry:

> Date      14/04/2019 23:35:37
>   SQL Server hosting availability group 'AG_PROD' did not receive a
>   process event signal from the Windows Server Failover Cluster within
>   the lease timeout period.
>
> Date      14/04/2019 23:35:37
>   SQL Server hosting availability group 'AG_PROD' did not receive a process
>   event signal from the Windows Server Failover Cluster within the lease 
>   timeout period.
>
> Date      14/04/2019 23:35:14
>   SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than > 15 seconds to complete on file [e:\sqlData\db.mdf] in database id 
>   6.  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000001128.  The offset of the latest long 
>   I/O is: 0x00010de65c0000
>
> Date      14/04/2019 23:33:10
>   BACKUP DATABASE WITH DIFFERENTIAL successfully processed 51459 pages in 61.045 > seconds (6.585 MB/sec).

As you see there is an IO-request that takes longer than 15 seconds, I would expect to find this in the `*_SQLDIAG_*.xel` file but no errors are found here.

When I check the cluster log I find following:

> 2019/04/14-23:35:09.430 INFO  [NM] Received request from client
>   address SQL1. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:09.444 INFO  [NM] Received request from
>   client address SQL1. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:09.459 INFO  [RES] Network Name
>   : Getting Read only private properties
>   2019/04/14-23:35:11.121 INFO  [RES] Network Name: Agent: Sending
>   request Netname/RecheckConfig to
>   NN:a09ce798-e8d3-4446-9e0b-d0fe72278d37:Netbios
>   2019/04/14-23:35:14.121 INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource final
>   status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:14.122 INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource
>   final status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:14.201 INFO  [API]
>   s_ApiGetQuorumResource final status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:14.201 INFO 
>   [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource final status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:14.202
>   INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource final status 0.
>   2019/04/14-23:35:14.202 INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource final
>   status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:14.282 INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource
>   final status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:14.283 INFO  [API]
>   s_ApiGetQuorumResource final status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:16.121 INFO 
>   [RES] Network Name: Agent: Sending request Netname/RecheckConfig to
>   NN:a09ce798-e8d3-4446-9e0b-d0fe72278d37:Netbios
>   2019/04/14-23:35:17.115 INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource final
>   status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:17.115 INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource
>   final status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:18.845 INFO  [RES] Network Name
>   : Dns: HealthCheck: SQL 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:18.845 INFO 
>   [RES] Network Name : Dns: End of Slow Operation, state:
>   Initialized/Reading, prevWorkState: Reading 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:21.121
>   INFO  [RES] Network Name: Agent: Sending request Netname/RecheckConfig
>   to NN:a09ce798-e8d3-4446-9e0b-d0fe72278d37:Netbios
>   2019/04/14-23:35:21.184 INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource final
>   status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:21.184 INFO  [API] s_ApiGetQuorumResource
>   final status 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:26.121 INFO  [RES] Network Name:
>   Agent: Sending request Netname/RecheckConfig to
>   NN:a09ce798-e8d3-4446-9e0b-d0fe72278d37:Netbios
>   2019/04/14-23:35:26.584 WARN  [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag] Failed to retrieve
>   data column. Return code -1 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:27.455 ERR   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group:
>   [hadrag] Failure detected, diagnostics heartbeat is lost  
>   2019/04/14-23:35:27.455 ERR   [RES]
>   SQL Server Availability Group : [hadrag] Availability Group
>   is not healthy with given HealthCheckTimeout and FailureConditionLevel
>   2019/04/14-23:35:27.455 ERR   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group : [hadrag] Resource
>   Alive result 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:27.455 ERR   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group: [hadrag]
>   Failure detected, diagnostics heartbeat is lost 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:27.455 ERR   [RES] SQL Server
>   Availability Group : [hadrag] Availability Group is not
>   healthy with given HealthCheckTimeout and FailureConditionLevel 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:27.455 ERR
>   [RES] SQL Server Availability Group : [hadrag] Resource Alive
>   result 0. 
>   2019/04/14-23:35:27.455 WARN  [RHS] Resource AG_PROD IsAlive has indicated failure.

So the HealthCheckTimeout was expired.

This is what is present at the system-eventlog at the time of the error:

> 14/04/2019 23:35:40 WARNING The IO operation at logical block address
>   0x8fd2b870 for Disk 1 (PDO name: \Device\MPIODisk1) was retried.
>
> 14/04/2019 23:35:27 ERROR Cluster resource 'AG_PROD' of type 'SQL
>   Server Availability Group' in clustered role 'AG_PROD' failed.
>
> Based on the failure policies for the resource and role, the cluster
>   service may try to bring the resource online on this node or move the
>   group to another node of the cluster and then restart it.  Check the
>   resource and group state using Failover Cluster Manager or the
>   Get-ClusterResource Windows PowerShell cmdlet.
>
> 14/04/2019 23:32:05 INFO  The WMI Performance Adapter service entered
>   the running state.

This is what I found in the application-eventlog:

> 14/04/2019 23:35:37 INFO  Always On: The local replica of availability
>   group 'AG_HIX_PROD' is going offline because either the lease expired
>   or lease renewal failed. This is an informational message only. No
>   user action is required.
>
> 14/04/2019 23:35:37 ERROR The lease between availability group
>   'AG_HIX_PROD' and the Windows Server Failover Cluster has expired. A
>   connectivity issue occurred between the instance of SQL Server and the
>   Windows Server Failover Cluster. To determine whether the availability
>   group is failing over correctly, check the corresponding availability
>   group resource in the Windows Server Failover Cluster.
>
> 14/04/2019 23:35:37 ERROR SQL Server hosting availability group
>   'AG_HIX_PROD' did not receive a process event signal from the Windows
>   Server Failover Cluster within the lease timeout period.

This is what I think happened:
The cluster didn't get info back in time from `sp_server_diagnostics` => HealthCheckTimeout was reached.
As consequence the cluster service started to take the resource offline.
Because the resource was being taken offline, we also got a lease-timeout.

So the machine didn't hung and caused a lease-timeout otherwise the other AG would also got a timeout.

I think `sp_server_diagnostics` is executed once per instance.
When I execute following query on each instance on the primary:

```
select spid,s.[status],host_name,s.program_name,host_process_id,
cmd,client_interface_name,original_login_name
from sys.sysprocesses p
inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions s on p.spid=s.session_id
where lastwaittype='SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP'
```

I get two records, one with the command 'SYSTEM_HEALTH_MO' and  host_process_id null and one with command 'EXECUTE' and a host_process_id. After tracking the host_process_id this was a RHS.exe process (so this was the cluster executing `sp_server_diagnostics`). 
The first record comes from a internal extended event, I think.
You can find it by using following query:

```
select * from sys.dm_xe_sessions
where [name] =N'sp_server_diagnostics session'
```

Is my conclusion a correct one or did I make a mistake in my analysis?
An additional question: does each AG have his own lease or is it only one lease per instance?

Comment: Is your SQL server virtualized?

Comment: @Alen: no this is a physical server.

Comment: You can try to increase the timeout in the cluster settings and look in the cluster log along with performance data for anything else. On a virtual instance i've seen this where the ESX host runs out of resources.

Comment: Honestly this isn't enough to go on. The lease issue seems to be a symptom of the previous failure and not the cause of the issue. We'd need to see the errorlog and cluster log from before `2019/04/14-23:35:26.584` to even start having an idea of what's going on. It'd also be required to look at the system event log and potentially even the application event log to get a much better picture. Currently, there just isn't enough information.

Comment: @SeanGallardy I updated my question with additional log info.

Comment: Thanks - so the lease timeout is a red herring. The main issue seems to be not returning the result set either at all or fast enough... You'll need to look a the system eventlog, the ring buffer for the time period, and the sqldiag* XE files to see what the worker threads, cpu utilization, memory, QP health, etc., are all stating. The issue could still be either in side or outside SQL Server and there is a really good chance there isn't enough data hanging around to find out, but it's worth a look.

Comment: @SeanGallardy: I did take a look at the logs but as you said nothing shows up that could caused the error. The only thing I see is that the 'Diagnostics Heartbeat is lost'. But what does that actually means? Is this the executing of sp_server_diagnostics that fails?

Comment: It means that something happened (unknown) where the result set wasn't returned in a timely manner. This could be anything, from high cpu, stalled scheduler, non-yielding scheduler, backup software freezing the vm, anti-cirus monopolizing cpu, memory pressure, I/O issues, etc. So there needs to be data to point in a direction, if there is none - dead in the water. If this happened once and never reoccurred, then I'm afraid there just isn't enough to go on.

Comment: I know this is an older question, but how much memory do the servers have installed?  How much memory is available to the SQL Server service?  Is the [Locked Pages in Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-2017) option enabled?  I ask these because I've seen memory pressure issues cause these timeouts more often than not.  You may want to fire up `perfmon` and baseline your memory usage to see if you find any correlation.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener: The server has 512GB of memory of which 395GB is assigned to the SQL Server. Also is Lock Pages in Memory enabled. I don't see any signs of memory pressure on this machine

Comment: In that case, if you have a MS Support agreement, I'd recommend opening up a case if you haven't done so already.

Comment: @FrederikVanderhaegen Sean Gallardy is MS Support.